# How to edit angle?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

[image]

I have drawn an angle using two lines XY and YZ.
I want to edit angle from StartPoint, MidPoint and EndPoint.
How to do it?

Comment: Can you show some code. How did you draw the lines?   It will make you question more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store your end-points in a list or an array
2. Add a mouse-button-down message handler to your form
3. Compare the click-position to the endpoints. If the user clicked near enough to an endpoint, then store its index, otherwise, store the value -1.
4. Add a mouse-move event handler to your form
5. In the mouse-move event handler, if the selected-point-index is not -1, then set the selected point's position to be the mouse position.
   This will allow you to click and drag any end point